# How to pass unsigned char array to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, unsigned

```
void GetKey(int date, unsigned char[] key)
{

}
```

I am trying to pass unsigned char array t a function but I get an error "expected a ')'" where "key" variable is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the brackets:

```
void GetKey(int date, unsigned char key[])
```

But note that it'll essentially degenerate into a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Use template function:

```
template<size_t N>
void GetKey(int date, unsigned char(&key)[N])
{
}
```

Comment: What actually happens when you write a template like that, using size_t instead of class or typename? And then, what would `unsigned char(&key)[N]` actually be? Sorry if these are stupid questions. I'm trying to rebuild my C++ knowledge ground-up.